# Change date and time format for the output in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, datetime

I need help to change the date and time format. The code below managed to change my date format but returned a wrong date from my output. Can anyone help?

Controller:

```
$timedate = [];

            foreach ($timeParts as $part) {
                $timedate[] = $part->textContent;
            }

            \\value for $timedate[0] is 15/05/2020
            $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($timedate[0])); 

            \\value for $timedate[1] is 03:53PM
            $time = $timedate[1];

            $datetime = array($date, $time);

            $output[] = [
                "Message" => $info,
                "Date & Time" => implode(" ", $datetime),
                "Location" => $title
            ];
```

Date Output:

```
[Date & Time] => 1970-01-01 3:53PM
```

Desired Ouput:

```
[Date & Time] => 2020-05-15 03:53:00
```

Comment: Please put here $timedate[0] variable value so i can identify which problem

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the question. Thank you.

Comment: Do a `str_eplace('/', '-', $date);` before converting the date.

Comment: Output : 01-May-2020. However I need to format it into yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: @spaceba I have added an answer. Check it. I just edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. Replace the `/` with `-` first.

```
$date = $timedate[0] . $timedate[1];
$date = str_replace('/', '-', $date);
echo $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date));
```

And `3:53PM` is not the same as `03:53:00`. `3:53PM = 15:53` and `03:53:00` = in the morning.

Comment: Exactly how I want! Thank you! >.<